# OnPreviewCanExecuteHandler not raising the ContextMenu command

Tags: c#, wpf

I want complete control over the ability to allow and disallow the execution of certain commands within a WPF application. To this end, I have the following sample code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CommandManager.AddPreviewCanExecuteHandler(this, OnPreviewCanExecuteHandler);
        Content = new TextBox();
        ((TextBox)Content).Focus();
    }


    void OnPreviewCanExecuteHandler(Object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CanExecute = false;
        e.ContinueRouting = false;
        e.Handled = true;
    }

}
```

This is only moderately successful - certain commands still execute. For example, the [EditingCommands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.editingcommands) appear to be unexecutable. However the [ContextMenu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.applicationcommands.contextmenu?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#system-windows-input-applicationcommands-contextmenu) command (through either gesture) is still executed, but within the context menu, the three commands Cut, Copy and Paste are all unexecutable.

After checking within the `OnPreviewCanExecuteHandler` method, it appears that the [CanExecuteRoutedEventHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.canexecuteroutedeventhandler?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) is not even raised for the ContextMenu command.

So, my question is why is the `OnPreviewCanExecuteHandler` not being raised for the ContextMenu command and more generally, why is the above code not marking every Command as unexecutable?

Comment: In your code, you are attempting to disable all commands by handling the PreviewCanExecute event, but certain commands like those in a ContextMenu behave differently.

Comment: If you want to disable all commands universally in your application, you would need a more global approach.

Comment: Would you mind expanding this please into a more complete answer?